# Complex (?) Unix Text Replace Command

Tags: command-line, unix, find-and-replace

What's the command line equivalent of:
For every file that contains "AAA" within its contents, find "BBB" and replace it with "CCC"

Thus, the command would match and replace BBB in a file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
AAA
Hello world!
BBB    
</body>
</html>
```

But Not in a file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Don't match me!
BBB    
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
grep -Rl AAA . | xargs sed -i -e 's/BBB/CCC/'
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this actually does/means? It looks like it worked for the question asker, but for anyone else who finds this post later, what does this actually _do_?

Comment: Sure.  `grep -R PATTERN DIR` means grep all files in DIR, recursively.  Normally it prints the lines that match PATTERN, but the `-l` option means only print matching filenames...

Comment: So the first half is printing out a list of files that contain `AAA`.  Then we use `xargs` to do something with each file.  In this case, run `sed`, replacing the first occurrence of `BBB` with `CCC`.  If all occurrences need to be replaced,  put a `g` after the last `/`.